# Save to internal storage large android bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

> ```
>   private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
>     ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
>     fileName="profile_1";
>     Date d1 = new Date();
>     Random r = new Random();
>     int i1 = r.nextInt(1000-1) + 1;
>     fileName=  "profile-"+i1+"-"+d1.getTime();
>     final File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
>     File mypath=new File(directory,""+fileName);
>     FileOutputStream fos = null;
>     try {
>         fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
>         bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
>         fos.close();
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>     return directory.getAbsolutePath();
> }
> ```

Its working, but the problem lies that it takes a lot of time once I take the picture from camera. Its giving me black screen, before returning back to activity. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

You **have** to perform long-running tasks in separate threads. Read [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) and [this official manual](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/multiple-threads/index.html)

Also look [this manual](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html), it's dedicated to `Bitmap` processing

Comment: okey. What am doing now is holding the bitmap in variable , Bitmap uploadbitmap. then on submit click.. i open new thread and uploadbitmap save it in internal storage. But is it wrong to hold large bitmap in variable.

Comment: @user3278732 check updated answer. I post a reference to the manual for working with bitmaps

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it in asynctask. This will allow to return to your activity instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

           String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
           File myDir = new File(root + "/SaveImage");    
           myDir.mkdirs();
           Random generator = new Random();
           int n = 10000;
           n = generator.nextInt(n);
           String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
           File file = new File (myDir, fname);
           if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
           try {
               FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
               finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
               out.flush();
               out.close();

           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, actually custom camera uses its best resolution which can't be in preview mode. 
Make resolution low, 
like Xiaomi Note 4G has best Resolution of 3600*4400, but if I take picture in this it will take lot of time so I make it down to 1280*720.

Black Screen Problem :
Set parameters to camera, and start preview and after that start preview display.

Eg.

```
camera.setparameters(params);
camera.startPreview();
camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
```